# Trouble declaring generic class with type of member of enum value

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm trying to declare a generic class in a way that will use a type, which is subject to change, without having to refactor my generic class every time the type changes. Like, if member `a` of an enum value `A` is a `String`, then declaring `Example<a>` is as good as declaring `Example<String>`.

However, I'm having trouble declaring it, since it seems that I can't resolve what I'm trying to do to a type. I'll try to provide a boiled-down example of my particulars, then I'll be able to describe the problem in more detail.

#### Code example

This `enum` declares the type of columns in a table. (It's basically a mapping from SQL data types to Java data types.)

```
public enum ColTypes {
    VARCHAR( String.class ),
    INTEGER( Integer.class );

    public final Class<?> dataType;
    public ColTypes (Class<?> dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }
}
```

This interface represents a column itself.

```
public interface Column<T> {
    public Object getColVal(T t);
}
```

Below is an example of a class that represents rows in some table. I have many different kinds of these classes, however, so I actually have some scripts set up to generate this code based on the database schema. They are essentially Dumb 'ol Data Objects, maybe a little more complex than that...

In order to let clients of such a class specify a column in the table for objects of that class, I include an `enum` of `Column`s inside of it. This way, you can use a `Column` of the class' inner enum as an argument so you can `getColVal()` generically instead of needing to specify particular getters. Look:

```
public class DBRow {
    private String foo;
    private Integer bar;
    public DBRow(String foo, Integer bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    public String getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }
    public Integer getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public enum DBCols implements Column<DBRow> {
        FOO( ColTypes.VARCHAR ) {
            public Object getColVal(DBRow r) {
                return r.getFoo();
            }
        },
        BAR( ColTypes.INTEGER ) {
            public Object getColVal(DBRow r) {
                return r.getBar();
            }
        };

        public final ColType colType;
        public DBCols(ColType colType) {
            this.colType = colType;
        }
    }
}
```

So you could hypothetically, for some `DBRow row`, call `DBRow.FOO.getValue(row)` instead of doing `row.getFoo()`. Useful for passing either `DBRow.FOO` or `DBRow.BAR` as an argument!

This class is a very simplified version of a class I have which works on collections of database objects by using that very strategy.

```
public abstract class ColValsGetter<T> {
    protected List<T> objs;
    protected Column<T> col;
    protected ColValsGetter(List<T> objs, Column<T> col) {
        this.objs = objs;
        this.col = col;
    }
    protected Object getColValForObj(int index) {
        return col.getColVal(objs.get(index));
    }
}
```

And here is a simple example of how it gets used in a concrete class. I would have one for the `BAR` column too. The reason that I do not make these classes generic is the fact that the logic to work with each column is very particular to the column, so it's difficult to abstract most of that behavior so that I can make these `ColValsGetter`s take the `Column` type that they are working with as a type parameter.

```
public class DBRowFooColValsGetter extends ColValsGetter<DBRow> {
    private String fooVal;
    public DBRowFooColValsGetter(List<DBRow> rows) {
        super(rows, DBRow.DBCols.FOO);
    }
    public void complexLogicForFooOnly(int i) {
        fooVal = (String) getColValForObj(i);
        // do a lot of stuff that only makes sense for the FOO column
    };
}
```

#### The problem

Now, my issue is with potential changes to the types in our schema. (I know, sounds fishy, but just ignore that.) The cast to `String` that I do will cause a `ClassCastException` if the `FOO` column changes to an `INTEGER` type. I would much rather declare `ColValsGetter<T, E>` and let its `getColValForObj(int)` method return an `E`. However, declaring it as something like `ColValsGetter<DBRow, String>` is no good, since it suffers from the same problem. What I would like to declare is something like:

```
public class DBRowFooColValsGetter extends
    ColValsGetter<DBRow, DBRow.DBCols.FOO.colType.dataType>
```

This way, if the schema changes, the class will automatically adjust. (Please believe me when I say that even though I can't abstract the behavior of these `ColValsGetter`s to make them generic for the columns, I can abstract the data type.)

My attempt to do this fails, however. Eclipse says that `DBRow.DBCols.FOO` cannot be resolved to a type. I *think* I understand why, since `dataType` is a `Class` object, but when I add `.class` at the end I get a syntax error ("Identifier expected.") Shouldn't I be able to get the type I want out of the enum values at compile time?

I'd really like to be able to accomplish this behavior somehow. Any ideas? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Java generics are type erased at compile-time. `FOO.colType.dataType` is not a type, but a variable, the contents of which are not set until run-time so not available to the compiler. I think in this case the Java type system will be unable to help you.

Comment: @ggovan Oh, so the enum values are constructed at runtime... I was afraid this would be the case. So even though I'm declaring `ColTypes.VARCHAR` with a type so explicitly, I can't wiggle that `String` out of it? What about passing in the `Class` object?

Comment: You can't do it basically because every instance of an enum has the same methods. They share the same signatures, because methods are defined at the enum level, not the instance level. They all "look the same".

Comment: Indeed, Java Enums are just a bunch of statically instantiated instances of some base object (``enum`` at the root)

Comment: It's not being _declared_ with a type, but being assigned with a type. Perhaps Enums are not the best way to do this as they all have the same type information.

Comment: @Bohemian I follow, but do their members "look the same?"

Comment: The point is that the actual enum instances don't exist at compile-time, which is the only time generic type information exists in Java thanks to type-erasure. You can't use the members of an enum as a parameter to a generic, period.

Comment: @aruisdante Got it, I'll abandon the approach. I'm still hoping for any creative solutions for me to get the end result I want, though.

Comment: I'm confused why the ``ColValsGetter<DBRow, String>`` approach wasn't meeting your needs. If you REALLY wanted to , you could alias a MSQL type to a Java type my simply extending the Java class, I.E. ``class VARCHAR extends String``.

Comment: @aruisdante except that `String` is final in Java

Comment: Ah, right, forgot about that bit. Well, either way, it seems like you're essentially trying to make an ORM, so you might want to check out how some of the big-time Java ORMs do it, like Hibernate or ActiveObjects or JPA, etc.

Comment: @aruisdante Yeah, I didn't know how I could thin my question down without leaving important information out... but basically I don't want to write the type explicitly since it may be subject to change. The failure underneath would be relatively silent (written to a log, but that's about it) if I failed a cast.

Comment: But I mean, at some point the type has to be set somewhere, because Java is strongly/statically typed. It seems like you basically are looking for the Java equivalent of a ``typedef``, so that you don't have to make sure to change the type everywhere you use it.

Comment: @aruisdante either that or a preprocessor macro...

Comment: Sadly Java has neither. The closest you can get is making a wrapper class that contains the raw Java class as its only public member, but that starts getting real dicey for immutable object types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to be able to change the enum and have everything else remain compilable.

That's pretty impossible as types are not really first-class data in Java.  Your client code needs to use a strongly typed object and you can't get that back from a heterogeneous enum or any other heterogeneous data structure at runtime.

You could include these getters like functional objects in the enum and use delegation to embed business logic, but you're still going to end up casting.

```
public class ColValsGetter<T> {
    protected List<T> objs;
    protected Column<T> col;
    public ColValsGetter(List<T> objs, Column<T> col) {
        this.objs = objs;
        this.col = col;
    }
    public T getColValForObj(int index) {
        return col.getColVal(objs.get(index));
    }
}
public class ColValsGetterFactory< T > {
    public ColValsGetterFactory() {}
    public ColValsGetter< T > make( List< T > lt, Column< T > col ) {
        return new ColValsGetter< T >( lt, col );
    }
}
public enum ColTypes {
    VARCHAR( String.class, new ColValsGetterFactory< String >() ),
    INTEGER( Integer.class, new ColValsGetterFactory< Integer >() );

    public final Class<?> dataType;
    public final ColValsGetterFactory< ? > gf;
    public < T > ColTypes ( Class< T > dataType, ColValsGetterFactory< T > gf ) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
        this.gf = gf;
    }
}

public class DBRowFooColValsGetter {
    private String fooVal;
    private ColValsGetter< String > getter;
    public DBRowFooColValsGetter( List< DBRow > rows ) {
        this.getter = ( ColValsGetter< String > )DBRow.DBCols.FOO.colType.gf.make( rows, DBRow.DBCols.FOO );
    }
    public void complexLogicForFooOnly( int i ) {
        fooVal = getter.getColValForObj( i );
        // do a lot of stuff that only makes sense for the FOO column
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm fine with casting as long as I can be certain that I won't have a `ClassCastException`. Is there a way I can rewrite the cast to `ColValsGetter<String>` so I don't have to write `String` explicitly?

Comment: I think you meant statically typed, not strongly typed. And no, because Java is statically typed. All of the type information of all objects MUST exist at compile type. You could write some kind of incredibly black-magic introspection that figures out what the type it should cast to is and passes it to the function that does the casting, but a function for each cast type needs to exist, you can't dynamically produce the cast, and you're going to need totally separate pipelines for each cast type.